# loading different env-files in react-native for different schemes (ios)

Tags: react-native, environment-variables

I'm trying to setup different schemes for react native with different .env-files. I have followed [this tutorial](https://ajaysidhu17.medium.com/configure-production-and-staging-environments-in-react-native-6c0d0faad034), but something doesn't work. I have 2 .env-files:

```
// .env.production
STAGE=prod

// .env.development
STAGE=dev
```

I have created 2 schemes in xcode with a pre-actions run script for build, with the following content (I've set the "Provide build settings from" to "myApp"):

```
// scheme: myApp
echo ".env.production" > /tmp/envfile

// scheme: myApp-dev
echo ".env.development" > /tmp/envfile
```

When starting the scheme 'myApp', it loads the "STAGE=prod" variable. But when changing to a different scheme, it looks like the STAGE-value is cached, because it still says "prod". Even when restarting the metro bundler (`npx react-native start --reset-cache)`, it keeps showing the "cached" version.

A year ago, I tried [this tutorial](https://medium.com/armenotech/configure-environment-variables-with-react-native-config-for-ios-and-android-7079c0842d8b) and it worked back then, but now it doesn't work anymore, I followed the same steps.

---

I was also trying out react-native-dotenv instead of react-native-config, but it doesn't work either.

Does someone know the correct solution for react native v 0.72.3?

Comment: I'm in the exact same shoes as you, have you been able to resolve this somehow? The only way I can is to restart the build, but it's very annoying having to wait till the end of the build only to realize it used the wrong env variables...